# Exporting multiple tables to multiple CSV files

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv

I have many tables in my **database** in the app. During the app use, these tables are created by the user and also their names.

I would like to export all tables, each one to a single **.CSV** file with the table's name.

For example, I have 3 tables named 1, 2 and 3. I would like to export and them create files 1.csv, 2.csv and 3.csv.

I really appreciate some help, because I could not find any answer in the web.

I am using some classes called CSVReader and CSVWriter, which are very popular.

Here in my method to export. It does not show any error, but no file is exported:

```
public void exportTables (View view) {
    File dbFile = getDatabasePath("database.db");
    Banco dbhelper = new Banco(getApplicationContext());
    File exportDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    if (!exportDir.exists()) {
        exportDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(exportDir, tableName +".csv");

    try {

        file.createNewFile();
        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_sequence'", null);
        csvWriter.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

        while(curCSV.moveToNext()) {
            // Table columns
            String arrStr[] ={curCSV.getString(0),curCSV.getString(1)};
            csvWriter.writeNext(arrStr);
        }

        csvWriter.close();

        curCSV.close();
    }
    catch(Exception sqlEx) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "FILE EXPORTED WITH SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Are there any rows returned in your `curCSV`?

Comment: Also where is this `tableName` in `new File(exportDir, tableName +".csv");` coming from? You should be creating these files inside the while

Comment: Do you need to do this in Java? The sqlite3 shell program makes this easy: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_export

Comment: @Bentaye First of all, thanks for your attention. Well, I guess I got your point. First, maybe I need a loop to read the table name and create the file right? Well, the theory maybe is this but I still do not know how to do it haha.

Comment: @Shawn Oh really? Because I really need it in Java. It is an Android App. But is good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @John I can help if you give me the list of columns returned by the query. Why do you only get the values at index 0 and 1?

Comment: @Bentaye Thanks for your kindness. Well, the index are just 0 and 1 because there just 2 columns in each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually a 2 steps process:

1 - List table names

Your first query

```
SELECT * 
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type='table' 
AND name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata' 
AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_sequence'
```

returns a list of tables and looks like this

```
type  |  name  | tbl_name | rootpage |       sql        |
------+--------+----------+----------+------------------+
table | table1 |  table1  |     2    | CREATE TABLE ... |
table | table2 |  table2  |     2    | CREATE TABLE ... |
table | table3 |  table3  |     2    | CREATE TABLE ... |
```

You could simply return the names instead of all the columns

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type='table' 
AND name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata' 
AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_sequence'
```

You need to read each row to get table names

2 - Then for each table you need create a file and query the table, ex:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

Then stick these in your file

**CODE:**

I did not test that code but you should be able to make it work:

This first method will list the table names

```
private static List<String> listTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor tableListCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_sequence'", null);
    while(tableListCursor.moveToNext()) {
        // get the name of the table
        tableNames.add(tableListCursor.getString(0));
    }
    tableListCursor.close();

    return tableNames;
}
```

This second method will dump a table to a file

```
private static void dumpTableToCsvFile(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    try {
        // Query the data in the table
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);

        File file = new File(exportDir, tableName +".csv");
        file.createNewFile();

        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        // Write the table data to the file
        csvWriter.writeNext(cursor.getColumnNames());
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String arrStr[] = { cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1) };
            csvWriter.writeNext(arrStr);
        }
        // close cursor and writer
        cursor.close();
        csvWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

And you use them this way:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
List<String> tableNames = listTables(db);
for(String tableName : tableNames) {
    dumpTableToCsvFile(db, tableName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I get it and it worked!!! If you don't mind, I just discover an stranger behavior... The commands to create the .csv file works fine in Android 5. But in Android 6, it does not create the file. Do you know why?

Comment: @John Great! Sorry but I am not an Android expert. You might need to create an other question for this, I have no idea of what could cause that issue.

Comment: Would you mind to look this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907133/android-importing-multiple-csv-files-to-multiple-tables-in-sqlite-database