# Android - Importing multiple .CSV Files to multiple tables in SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv

I have in my Android device a folder with multiple .CSV files.

I want to import all of them to my SQLite Database, but each file must be a different table.

All .CSV file are simple. They have just one column.

Example:

**File.CSV**

```
12345

123

00000000
```

**AnotherFile.CSV**

```
XXXXX

ZZZZZZZZZZ

FFFF
```

Here is my method and it is not working. I could not understand why:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void importaTabelas() {

    //Check the read permission
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        try {

            //Check if the folder exists
            File importDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/ENEL/IMPORTADOS/");
            if (!importDir.exists())
            {
                importDir.mkdirs();
            }

            //Read all file names
            for (File f : importDir.listFiles()) {

                if (f.isFile()) {

                    //Put the files names into variable nomeArq
                    nomeArq = f.getName();

                    //Take off the file extension .csv
                    if (nomeArq.indexOf(".") > 0)
                        nomeArq = nomeArq.substring(0, nomeArq.lastIndexOf("."));

                    SQLiteDatabase db = this.banco.getWritableDatabase();

                    try {

                        //Create table with the name of the .csv file
                        String criaTab = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + nomeArq +  " (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, codigo varchar (50))";
                        db.execSQL(criaTab);
                        db.close();

                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //String for the file location
                    String fn = importDir + "/" + nomeArq + ".csv";

                    //Reads the file
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fn);

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                    //ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                    String line = "";

                    //db.beginTransaction();

                    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                        //String[] colums = line.split("\t");

                        //String[] colums = line.split(";");

                        Toast.makeText(this, line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //contentValues.put("codigo", line);

                        //db.insert(nomeArq, null, contentValues);

                        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + nomeArq +  " (codigo) VALUES ('" + line + "')");

                    }

                    //db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    //db.endTransaction();

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Catch!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    else {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

    }

}
```

Would you help me to make it works? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just use the SQLite command line shell?

Comment: @user1461607 Sorry, but I don't get it. It is an Android App, will it works?

Comment: @John How does it not work? do you have an error in the logs? Does it create the tables but they are empty? What is happening exactly?

Comment: @Bentaye Actually, I made some corrections to the code. Please check the updated code. Now it creates the table correctly but don't insert the file content to the table. I put some toasts to debug and see that it is reading the file content correctly, but in the moment to save the content to the created table, it goes to the catch exception. I really don't know why.

Comment: Could be this line `FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fn);` you should not try to recreate the path to the file, you can pass it the file itself, try `FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(f);` instead. What is the stack trace saying, please add it to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code into a bunch of smaller methods. Each method is responsible for one thing, which is good practice, try to do that any time you can.

I only did a few changes:

- The line creating the `FileReader` now uses the file (less error prone)
- Changed the way you insert by creating a single insert query so you have less database accesses (ie like this: `INSERT INTO table(codigo) VALUES ('XXXX'), ('ZZZZ'), ('FFFF');` )
- Changed the text in the Toasts to identify better where your error comes from.

Try it out and see if you can find your error better.
(I did not try to compile the code so you might have to tweak it a little but should be fine overall)

main import method:

```
public void importaTabelas() {

    //Check the read permission
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            makeDirs();

            //Read all file names
            for (File f : importDir.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    importFile(f);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not import tables! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }

}
```

Make the directories

```
private void makeDirs() {
    //Check if the folder exists
    File importDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/ENEL/IMPORTADOS/");
    if (!importDir.exists()) {
        importDir.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

Import a single file

```
private void importFile(File f) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.banco.getWritableDatabase();

        //Put the files names into variable nomeArq
        String nomeArq = f.getName();

        //Take off the file extension .csv
        if (nomeArq.indexOf(".") > 0)
            nomeArq = nomeArq.substring(0, nomeArq.lastIndexOf("."));

        createTable(db, nomeArq);

        String insertQuery = buildImportQuery(f, nomeArq);
        db.execSQL(insertQuery);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not import file. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Builds the insert query for a specific file

```
private String buildImportQuery(File f, String nomeArq) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        //Reads the file
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;

        sb.append("INSERT INTO " + nomeArq +  " (codigo) VALUES ");
        boolean addComma = false;
        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.length() > 0) {
                if(addComma) {
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                sb.append("('" + line.trim() + "')");
                addComma = true;
            }
        }
        sb.append(";");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not write query. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Creates a single table

```
private void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    try {
        //Create table with the name of the .csv file
        String criaTab = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName +  " (id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, codigo varchar (50))";
        db.execSQL(criaTab);
        db.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not create table " + tableName + "." +  e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! u r unbelievable! It is much more organized this way.

Comment: Just for your information, the problem in my code was the db.closed. I was closing db and then try to open it again. I just changed the db.close for the end of the method and it works.